# Make TypeScript aware of method added to object at runtime via mixin

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using a third party JavaScript library that uses a ["mixin"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) pattern to add properties to an arbitrary object. I would like TypeScript to be aware of these properties without using inheritance or adding them explicitly to the type definition.

```
function ThirdParty(objectToMutate: any): void { 
  objectToMutate.newMethod = function(): void { ... }
}

class MyClass { ... }

var myObject = new MyClass();

ThirdParty(myObject);

myObject.newMethod();
```

Is there a way to make TypeScript recognize `myObject.newMethod()` without adding `newMethod` to `MyClass` and without changing `ThirdParty`? I'm ok with monkey patches.

Comment: How would it recognize it if it didn't know about it?

Comment: I can change the interface declaration of the third party component, can type cast, etc. I'm hoping there is a way to tell the typescript compiler "the following properties have been added to `myObject`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an interface which consists of the added method(s), and then have the function return [an intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of the passed in type and this new interface:

```
interface ThirdPartyInstance {
    newMethod(): void;
}

function ThirdParty<T>(objectToMutate: T): T & ThirdPartyInstance {
    (objectToMutate as any).newMethod = function (): void {  };
    return objectToMutate as T & ThirdPartyInstance;
}

class MyClass {  }

var myObject = ThirdParty(new MyClass()); // myObject is of type MyClass & ThirdPartyInstance

myObject.newMethod();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ThirdPartyInstance%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20newMethod()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20ThirdParty%3CT%3E(objectToMutate%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%26%20ThirdPartyInstance%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(objectToMutate%20as%20any).newMethod%20%3D%20function%20()%3A%20void%20%7B%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20objectToMutate%20as%20T%20%26%20ThirdPartyInstance%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20myObject%20%3D%20ThirdParty(new%20MyClass())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyObject.newMethod()%3B))